# Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.2) class path

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

**What went wrong:**

> Execution failed for task *':app:preDebugBuild'.*
>   Android dependency `'androidx.core:core'` has different version for the compile (1.0.0- rc01) and runtime (1.0.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
>
> **Try:** 
>   Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at h../help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
   See  for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

---

> Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1